# How to use WHERE clauses for a complex JOIN query

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, left-join

I'm trying to make my data set smaller, where I'm currently bringing in data from 8 different tables. In order to do this, I'd like to use the WHERE clause to filter out unnecessary data, but I'm not sure how to do that for all 8 tables. This is my current query:

```
--GroupA first, to join the hits and sessions tables
SELECT 
GroupA_hits.session_id, GroupA_hits.hits_eventInfo_eventCategory, GroupA_hits.hits_eventInfo_eventAction, GroupA_hits.hits_eventInfo_eventLabel, GroupA_hits.cd126_hit_placeholder,
GroupA_sessions.session_id, GroupA_sessions.userId, GroupA_sessions.fullVisitorId, GroupA_sessions.visitNumber, GroupA_sessions.date,
GroupB_hits.session_id, GroupB_hits.hits_eventInfo_eventCategory, GroupB_hits.hits_eventInfo_eventAction, GroupB_hits.hits_eventInfo_eventLabel, GroupB_hits.cd126_hit_placeholder,
GroupB_sessions.session_id, GroupB_sessions.userId, GroupB_sessions.fullVisitorId, GroupB_sessions.visitNumber, GroupB_sessions.date,
GroupC_hits.session_id, GroupC_hits.hits_eventInfo_eventCategory, GroupC_hits.hits_eventInfo_eventAction, GroupC_hits.hits_eventInfo_eventLabel, GroupC_hits.cd126_hit_placeholder,
GroupC_sessions.session_id, GroupC_sessions.userId, GroupC_sessions.fullVisitorId, GroupC_sessions.visitNumber, GroupC_sessions.date,
GroupD_hits.session_id, GroupD_hits.hits_eventInfo_eventCategory, GroupD_hits.hits_eventInfo_eventAction, GroupD_hits.hits_eventInfo_eventLabel, GroupD_hits.cd126_hit_placeholder,
GroupD_sessions.session_id, GroupD_sessions.userId, GroupD_sessions.fullVisitorId, GroupD_sessions.visitNumber, GroupD_sessions.date
FROM `GroupA-bigquery.170369603.ga_flat_hits_202104*` GroupA_hits
LEFT JOIN `GroupA-bigquery.170369603.ga_flat_sessions_202104*` GroupA_sessions
ON (
    GroupA_hits.session_id = GroupA_sessions.session_id
)
--Next, join GroupB to GroupA
LEFT JOIN `GroupB-bigquery.170359716.ga_flat_hits_202104*` GroupB_hits
ON (
    GroupB_hits.session_id = GroupA_hits.session_id
)
LEFT JOIN `GroupB-bigquery.170359716.ga_flat_sessions_202104*` GroupB_sessions
ON (
    GroupB_sessions.session_id = GroupA_sessions.session_id
)
--Now, join GroupC to GroupA
LEFT JOIN `GroupC-bigquery.170726426.ga_flat_hits_202104*` GroupC_hits
ON (
    GroupC_hits.session_id = GroupA_hits.session_id
)
LEFT JOIN `GroupC-bigquery.170726426.ga_flat_sessions_202104*` GroupC_sessions
ON (
    GroupC_sessions.session_id = GroupA_sessions.session_id
)
--Next, join GroupD to GroupA
LEFT JOIN `GroupD-bigquery.170374765.ga_flat_hits_202104*` GroupD_hits
ON (
    GroupD_hits.session_id = GroupA_hits.session_id
)
LEFT JOIN `GroupD-bigquery.170374765.ga_flat_sessions_202104*` GroupD_sessions
ON (
    GroupD_sessions.session_id = GroupA_sessions.session_id
)
```

I would like to also include the below clauses, these are all the same column names in the different _hits tables. This is what I've tried, but I get a "This query returned no results" back. I think it's because the way this query is written, BigQuery is looking for a row where all of these exist in one hit (is my assumption), which, there won't be any. But I'd like it to look through these four tables and grab all matching rows.

```
WHERE GroupA_hits.hits_eventInfo_eventCategory = 'rewards'
AND GroupB_hits.hits_eventInfo_eventCategory = 'rewards'
AND GroupC_hits.hits_eventInfo_eventCategory = 'rewards'
AND GroupD_hits.hits_eventInfo_eventCategory = 'rewards'
AND GroupA_hits.hits_eventInfo_eventAction = 'redeem points confirm'
AND GroupB_hits.hits_eventInfo_eventAction = 'redeem points confirm'
AND GroupC_hits.hits_eventInfo_eventAction = 'redeem points confirm'
AND GroupD_hits.hits_eventInfo_eventAction = 'redeem points confirm'
AND GroupA_hits.hits_eventInfo_eventLabel = 'gas savings'
AND GroupB_hits.hits_eventInfo_eventLabel = 'gas savings'
AND GroupC_hits.hits_eventInfo_eventLabel = 'gas savings'
AND GroupD_hits.hits_eventInfo_eventLabel = 'gas savings'
AND GroupA_hits.cd126_hit_placeholder Is Not NULL
AND GroupB_hits.cd126_hit_placeholder Is Not NULL
AND GroupC_hits.cd126_hit_placeholder Is Not NULL
AND GroupD_hits.cd126_hit_placeholder Is Not NULL
```

Comment: you have to provide sample data and desired output or make a fiddle : https://dbfiddle.uk/

Answer (score 0):

Consider moving the `WHERE` conditions into `ON` clauses to filter those tables during the `LEFT JOIN` operations:

```sql
...
FROM `GroupA-bigquery.170369603.ga_flat_hits_202104*` GroupA_hits
LEFT JOIN `GroupA-bigquery.170369603.ga_flat_sessions_202104*` GroupA_sessions
ON GroupA_hits.session_id = GroupA_sessions.session_id
AND GroupA_hits.hits_eventInfo_eventCategory = 'rewards'
AND GroupA_hits.hits_eventInfo_eventAction = 'redeem points confirm'
AND GroupA_hits.hits_eventInfo_eventLabel = 'gas savings'
AND GroupA_hits.cd126_hit_placeholder Is Not NULL

--Next, join GroupB to GroupA
LEFT JOIN `GroupB-bigquery.170359716.ga_flat_hits_202104*` GroupB_hits
ON GroupB_hits.session_id = GroupA_hits.session_id
AND GroupB_hits.hits_eventInfo_eventCategory = 'rewards'
AND GroupB_hits.hits_eventInfo_eventAction = 'redeem points confirm'
AND GroupB_hits.hits_eventInfo_eventLabel = 'gas savings'
AND GroupB_hits.cd126_hit_placeholder Is Not NULL

LEFT JOIN `GroupB-bigquery.170359716.ga_flat_sessions_202104*` GroupB_sessions
ON  GroupB_sessions.session_id = GroupA_sessions.session_id

--Now, join GroupC to GroupA
LEFT JOIN `GroupC-bigquery.170726426.ga_flat_hits_202104*` GroupC_hits
ON GroupC_hits.session_id = GroupA_hits.session_id
AND GroupC_hits.hits_eventInfo_eventCategory = 'rewards'
AND GroupC_hits.hits_eventInfo_eventAction = 'redeem points confirm'
AND GroupC_hits.hits_eventInfo_eventLabel = 'gas savings'
AND GroupC_hits.cd126_hit_placeholder Is Not NULL

LEFT JOIN `GroupC-bigquery.170726426.ga_flat_sessions_202104*` GroupC_sessions
ON GroupC_sessions.session_id = GroupA_sessions.session_id

--Next, join GroupD to GroupA
LEFT JOIN `GroupD-bigquery.170374765.ga_flat_hits_202104*` GroupD_hits
ON GroupD_hits.session_id = GroupA_hits.session_id
AND GroupD_hits.hits_eventInfo_eventCategory = 'rewards'
AND GroupD_hits.hits_eventInfo_eventAction = 'redeem points confirm'
AND GroupD_hits.hits_eventInfo_eventLabel = 'gas savings'
AND GroupD_hits.cd126_hit_placeholder Is Not NULL 

LEFT JOIN `GroupD-bigquery.170374765.ga_flat_sessions_202104*` GroupD_sessions
ON GroupD_sessions.session_id = GroupA_sessions.session_id
```

Answer (score 0):

> BigQuery is looking for a row where all of these exist in one hit (is my assumption), which, there won't be any.

Sounds like you want each option in an `OR` group, which could be further simplified like this:

```
WHERE 
       'rewards' IN (GroupA_hits.hits_eventInfo_eventCategory, GroupB_hits.hits_eventInfo_eventCategory, GroupC_hits.hits_eventInfo_eventCategory, GroupD_hits.hits_eventInfo_eventCategory)
   AND 'redeem points confirm' IN (GroupA_hits.hits_eventInfo_eventAction, GroupB_hits.hits_eventInfo_eventAction, GroupC_hits.hits_eventInfo_eventAction, GroupD_hits.hits_eventInfo_eventAction)
   AND 'gas savings' IN (GroupA_hits.hits_eventInfo_eventLabel, GroupB_hits.hits_eventInfo_eventLabel, GroupC_hits.hits_eventInfo_eventLabel, GroupD_hits.hits_eventInfo_eventLabel)
   AND COALESCE(GroupA_hits.cd126_hit_placeholder, GroupB_hits.cd126_hit_placeholder, GroupC_hits.cd126_hit_placeholder, GroupD_hits.cd126_hit_placeholder) Is Not NULL
```

Note that I'm making some assumptions about how BigQuery handles ANSI standard SQL, as I'm not a regular BigQuery user.